# When set root view controller programmatically navigation and tab bar missing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

App delegate code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let myViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController") as UIViewController
if self.window != nil {
                self.window!.rootViewController = myViewController

            }
```

When I load app without this code everything is fine.
But if I run with this code view is loaded but navigation and tab bar are missing.
What am I missing here?
I am using storyboard.

Answer (score 3):

This is code that work:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let mainRootController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainViewController") as UIViewController
if self.window != nil {

                let navigationController:UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as UINavigationController
                navigationController.viewControllers = [mainRootController]

                self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
}
return true
```

Answer (score 0):

Before adding root view controller you must be allocate memory for navigation controller and then navigation controller take as a root view controller .

```
 UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourViewController];

             [[UINavigationBar appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

           self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

Comment: swift programming lalnguage